# BotDisabledByAdmin error from Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Our customers upload our app as a custom Microsoft Teams app that has a bot and install it into a Team. From then on, we send notifications to users directly on their Microsoft Teams app via the bot.

This has been working fine for a long time. Recently, we started getting back BotDisabledByAdmin response when we try to post messages to the users in one of the tenants.

We realised that the Tenant’s admin has setup policies to block custom apps. This prevented us to even uninstall and reinstall the app into any Team in the Tenant.

After noticing that, the Admin has changed the policies to allow all custom apps. We had to wait 3 days for the changes to take effect and after that, we were able to uninstall and reinstall the app freshly.

Although we are able to use Botframework APIs to search users to find their ID etc., we are unable to post messages to any of the users. We are still receiving `BotDisabledByAdmin` error.

I’m attaching all the policies that are set in the Tenant under Microsoft Teams admin portal. The blacked out app under Global policy is our app.

Are there any other policies, settings or restrictions that we could double check to resolve this issue?

[image]
[image: Our App allowed explicitly as a custom app]
[image]
[image]

Comment: All the permissions seem to be ok. However, if a user has a policy where "Custom apps" is turned off, that means they cannot message the app and the app cannot message them. Please do verify that

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT where do manage user policies? Is it under Teams admin > Users > Manage users > select user > Policies? Or is there a different place for it?

Comment: Yes, its available under Teams admin > Users > Manage users > Policies > Assigned policies.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT We don't see any conflicting policies assigned to the users but we still receive this error. What could we do about this? Can we schedule a support call to debug deeper into this?

Comment: Does uninstalling/installing the app helped? Can you verify by uninstalling and reinstalling? Or updating MS Teams version?

Comment: No. we tried it multiple times and it's the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: In your 'Apps' section , Please try to unblock your app by right clicking on it if its blocked anyhow.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT There is no such option to unlock the app anywhere when right clicking. can we escalate this issue? This has been pending for a long time and we are not getting any help. Can we share you the tenant id and the Azure ID for you to tell us what is happening?

Comment: Could you please share your botID and timestamp whenever you get the above-mentioned error? Please share it on microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: Could you please share your botID and timestamp whenever you get the above-mentioned error? Please share it on microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Comment: I shared via email.

Comment: We are checking this internally with engineering team. We will inform you once we get further update. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please check if the bot ID is associated with 2 Teams apps, one in the global catalog (blocked by permission policy) and one in the tenant catalog (allowed by policy)? Sometimes this type of case brings out the error.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT yes. that was the case. However, the admin has later allowed all Third-party apps and Custom apps from the policy and we still receive this error. We waiting 4 days after the policy is updated to make sure the changes are applied. Unfortunately, no luck. We still receive the error.

Comment: Navigate to Teams apps > Permission policies.
Select Allow specific apps and block others for Third-party apps and Custom apps
Ensure that your app is allowed for Third-party apps.
Ensure your app for Teams app is allowed for Custom apps.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT that didn't help. We already tried it like I said in the comments above. However, we finished Teams Store validation and the customer reinstalled the app and it seems to work now.

Comment: @aBadAssCowboy Did you manage to solve this issue? We are having a similar problem.

Comment: @DinaF Our customer has removed the app and reauthorised it multiple times and through out this process, it has started working. It was a shame that Microsoft cannot answer what is going wrong with these permissions and couldn't support us well with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

These permissions policies are buggy as all hell, and stop working reliably day-to-day.  Frequently I've seen attempts to message users fail, then work, and then fail again within the space of an hour, with no changes made whatsoever.  Then suddenly it'll be fine for months at a time.

You can never rule out that it's not some transient outage on Microsoft's part, or stuff clunking around replicating incompletely in the Teams back-end.